Why use a class for specifying a collection of valid arguments?
Looking through different Python modules I have several times seen that classes are used to define a collection of valid arguments and I wonder what the purpose of this approach is.
E.g. consider the following class:
class ArgumentOption:
    ARG1 = "ARG1"
    ARG2 = "ARG2"
    ARG3 = 3

What is the purpose of this approach as opposed to just defining a set, list, tuple, or something else containing the same options? Many times I see that functions might as well have take a string, int or whatever as argument instead of an instance of a class as defined above.

It gives you a namespace, basically - do_thing(ArgumentOption.ARG1).

And usually such classes will be enum.Enum subclasses - semantically close to enums in other languages.

@jonrsharpe thanks for pointing out that it gives namespaces. I am not too familiar with this concept. But I instantly recall hearing about it in C++ where I've seen using namespace std. Here I can see that the code gets (subjectivly) more readable - but what is the purpose for Python? Is it just a clever way of limiting the valid arguments to a prespecified collection? I would assume that using the class would take up a tiny bit of memory for every instance - so why not just pass a string, int or whatever and check if the passed argument is in a set with the same options?

You're using Python, you're already not caring that much about memory that it would make a big difference. Also, you're not instantiating any classes here, you are just passing strings or numbers. Those strings or numbers are simply stored as attributes of a class object.

@deceze, I see your point about just passing the argument and that Python is not a good choice if speed and memory is very important. Yet, I am also hoping for some confirmation that using classes in this way is just to define a collection of valid arguments - or are there any other benifits from this approach?

It's very much just that. And as STerliakov said, usually you'd use an Enum instead of a "loose" class like this, but it works either way.

It increases code safety. If you just used string literals, you could easily make a typo that would go unnoticed. But if you mistype a class attribute you'll get an exception. And IDEs can warn about it while you're coding.
